# Adding turf.js polygons from shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, geojson, turf

I'd like to know if there is any tool I can use to import polygons from a shapefile.

Is there any way to import a feature class in turf format or I should use GeoJSON?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert shapfiles to geojson using [shapefile-js](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js) library or other similar libraries, in the browser without making any server calls.

then use that geojson data with Turf.js

Answer (score 1):

What are you importing into? [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) would be my choice for converting shapefiles into various other formats, including GeoJSON:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.json input.shp
```

Turf is 100% javascript by the way, so there is no turf format apart from GeoJSON (also referred to as a [FeatureCollection](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-featurecollection) in the docs and modules):

> [Turf uses GeoJSON for all geographic data](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf)